# Auto Email Google App Script: do while condition

Tags: google-apps-script

I been working on this script for long time, it is Google App script, it sends email alert  automatically to email provided, and I have script triggered at running every 1 minute.

so if cell total is greater than 201 it will send email to user. 
but the problem is it send email every minute script is ran.

I need help with coding where if email has been sent already once, it will not send again unless cell value is less than 201 again and goes back to greater than 201, 
I was thinking of making a cell which will contain text "Sent" or "Not Sent"

if it says "Not Sent" let the email code run if total is greater than 201
if is says "Sent" and total is greater than 201 don't let email code run..

I know I am not every clear but It has been very hard to get help on this.
Here is the code.

and if this works I'm sure lots of people can use this script for their use.

```
 function sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message);
}

function test_sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.setActiveCell('A2');
  var criterion_cutoff = 201;
  var i = 0;
  var addr;
  var subj;
  var msg;


  do {
    addr = cell.offset(i,0).getValue();
    subj = cell.offset(i,1).getValue();
    msg = cell.offset(i,2).getValue();
    criterion = cell.offset(i,3).getValue();

    if(criterion == criterion_cutoff) {
      sendEmail(addr,subj,msg);
     // Browser.msgBox('Sending email to: ' + addr);
    }
    i++;
      } while( cell.offset(i, 0).getValue().length > 0 )


  Browser.msgBox('Done!');
}
```

so I was think of adding if else condition outside of do while

```
 if(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(21,6).getValue() != 'Not Sent') {
    do {
        //same stuff as above
     } while(condition)

    }

   else 
       //don't know wht else to do in else condtion so just using googleclock
         SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,7).setValue('=GoogleClock()')
```

Comment: from reading your code, it seems that you check a whole column of cells and not just one. If anyone is ever up, the email will be sent, then you don't need to check the other cells (in the column) anymore?

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu yes and no, well there is 3 X 3 column, first column has emails, 2nd has subject and 3rd has msg. so you can think of it as 3 different checking condition application, I don't have to use all 3. I am only checking for row 2..my code is working only issue is I don't want to keep sending email if has been sent already once, and once only if cell is still greater than 201..if it goes back down to less than 201 it should send again.

Comment: @HenriqueAbreu I have almost got the solution myself, I will post it on here it someone needs to use it too.

Comment: I want to answer my own question but I can't for another 8 hours. I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I've figured it out on my own. I want to share my solution so other can use it.

so I have added 2 if else condtion 
first one will check if cell value is < 201
if it is less than 201 than set somecell example F5 = Not Sent

another if else loop that will check
if value of F5 != Sent and cell value == 201
than it will run the email code
and right after running that email code it will set cell F5 to Sent

so next time loop runs again it will not send email again unless value of cell is

but this has one minor issue it will only work for 1st row out of 3 rows, you can make it for all 3 rows by adding more if conditions, I don't need it so I am not worried about it.

```
  function sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(email_address, email_subject, email_message);
}

function test_sendEmail() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.setActiveCell('A2');
  var criterion_cutoff = 201;
  var i = 0;
  var addr;
  var subj;
  var msg;

  if((SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,4).getValue() < '201'))  {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,6).setValue('Not Sent');
  }
  else  
    if((SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,6).getValue() != 'Sent') && (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,4).getValue() == '201')) {
  do {
    addr = cell.offset(i,0).getValue();
    subj = cell.offset(i,1).getValue();
    msg = cell.offset(i,2).getValue();
    criterion = cell.offset(i,3).getValue();

    if(criterion == criterion_cutoff) {
      sendEmail(addr,subj,msg);
     // Browser.msgBox('Sending email to: ' + addr);
      SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2,6).setValue('Sent');
    }
    i++;
      } while( cell.offset(i, 0).getValue().length > 0 )

  Browser.msgBox('Done!');
}
    }
```